# no return statement in function returning non-void while using C++

Tags: c++, macros, return, compiler-warnings

I am trying to understand the C++(GCC compiler) expectation of `return` statement in a `non-void` function.

For example, running this piece of code is working fine:

```
int foo() 
{ 
    throw "blah";
}
```

While, on the other hand, if we try to use/call some function to complete the `throw`, it is facing the well known error/warning of:

```
no return statement in function returning non-void
```

for example:

```
void throw_blah() 
{
    throw "blah";
}

int foo() 
{ 
    throw_blah();
}
```

I am pretty curious about this as this is directly related to one of my other [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69554388/special-case-of-no-return-statement-in-lambda-function-c), where just like here, `throw` is working fine but using `macro` for `throw` is facing the same error.

Comment: If you are never going to return something, why do you declare the function as doing so?  Just make it return `void` if you are not going to return anything.  The compiler is trying to help you out with this by issuing a warning/error.

Comment: @NathanOliver One could imagine a slightly more complex example which was fully reasonable, like `int div_checked(a, b) { if(b) return a/b; else log_error_and_die(); }`.

Comment: @Sneftel Good point.  I forgot it would still issue if all paths don't have a return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler isn't going to go to very much trouble to detect this situation, because functions like `throw_blah` which are guaranteed to never return are rare, and because except in the simplest of situations, there's no way for it to reliably do so. If you have a function like `throw_blah` which is defined to never return, you can use the `[[noreturn]]` attribute to tell the compiler about it, and it will suppress the warning.

Note that `throw_blah` is the weird bit, not `foo`. If you called `exit` instead of `throw_blah` from `foo`, for instance, it wouldn't issue the error. That's because `exit` is marked as `[[noreturn]]`.